# why is undefined being added to my filtered list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, undefined

I'm trying to make write a node program that will read a file director and filter out those without a certain file extension.  (This is a challenge for [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode))  For some reason it adds to the list 'undefined'. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var fs = require('fs')

var path = process.argv[2];
var ext = process.argv[3];

var fileList = fs.readdir(path, function callback(err, list){
    if (err){
    throw err;
    }
    var filteredList = list.filter(function(fileName){  
    var extRx = new RegExp('\.' + 'md' + '$');
        return extRx.test(fileName);
    });
    console.log(filteredList.forEach(function(val){console.log(val)}));
});
```

Outputs:

```
             ACTUAL                                 EXPECTED                

   "CHANGELOG.md"                      ==    "CHANGELOG.md"                     
   "LICENCE.md"                        ==    "LICENCE.md"                       
   "README.md"                         ==    "README.md"                        
   "undefined"                         !=    ""                                 
   ""                                  !=
```

Comment: Need to see the actual list of file names in order to debug that.

Comment: Log the `list` and show us the result please

Comment: Side note: why `console.log(filteredList.forEach(function(val){console.log(val)}));` instead of just `console.log(filteredList)`?

Comment: @adeneo That should not matter, it should filter those out because they never match the regular expression. A string 'undefined' shouldn't match either though so it must be something wrong in the logging

Comment: @Randy - you're right, there's absolutely no way the filtered list could contain `undefined`, so it's the outer console log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it's actually an artifact of your console approach.  You're console logging each element in the filtered list, and *then* console logging the output of the forEach function.  The forEach function does not have a return value, so it's returning 'undefined' which your outer console log then logs.

Consider changing your console log to just:

```
console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: Nice catch!  Taking a second look at this, not sure why I did it that way.  Musta been tired.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include a runnable example so it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with the code that you didn't include, espacially when you don't even include the actual list of files that you're trying to filter.

See this example:

```
var list = [
    "CHANGELOG.md",
    "LICENCE.md",
    "README.md",
    "undefined",
    "",
];
var filteredList = list.filter(function(fileName){
    var extRx = new RegExp('\.' + 'md' + '$');
    return extRx.test(fileName);
});
console.log(filteredList);
```

This correctly filters out the values that you want.
Change your program to have one console.log statement to make sure that you know what is being printed:

```
console.log(filteredList);
```

or:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredList));
```

One advice - don't complicate it so much:

```
var filteredList = list.filter(function(fileName){
    var extRx = new RegExp('\.' + 'md' + '$');
    return extRx.test(fileName);
});
```

when all you need is:

```
var filteredList = list.filter(name => name.match(/\.md$/));
```

You will have less trouble debugging your code if you keep it simple.

### Update

After reading the comments I see that the `'md'` is just a placeholder and you're using command line arguments in the real code. In that case I would use `escape-string-regexp` to escape the string. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-string-regexp

When you use the `escape-string-regexp`:

```
var escape = require('escape-string-regexp');
```

You can do something like:

```
var extRx = new RegExp('[.]' + escape(ext) + '$');
```

where `ext` is the file extension that you got as a command line argument.

The `[.]` here is just my personal preference of writing a literal dot in regexes, I think it's more readable but it doesn't change any behavior here. The escaping is more important.

If you don't escape the string because you'd like your users to be able to use a custom regex instead of literal strings, then you should at least wrap the `new RegExp()` call in `try`/`catch` because it can throw exceptions on invalid regex syntax.

Comment: I hardcoded the `md` for this example but it's supposed to be a command line argument, hence the `new RegExp` object.  Does your advice still apply?

Comment: @DavidJ. if part of the regex comes from a command line argument then I would use [escape-string-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-string-regexp) to escape the string with `var escape = require('escape-string-regexp');` `var extRx = new RegExp('[.]' + escape(XXX) + '$');` where `XXX` is the command line argument. The `[.]` is just my personal preference of writing a literal dot in regexes, I think it's more readable but it doesn't change any behavior here. The escaping is more important.